# Best way to restrict access by URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, claims-based-identity

We are currently working on a website that allows different users to manage entities (documents, people, etc.). Each user has a list of groups that he belongs to, and when creating an entity, they can define the groups that they want them to belong to. The entities created can then be managed by users that belong to the same group.

To achieve that on normal navigation, we filter all index pages to show only the entities that belong to any of the groups the user belongs to, and we use claims to restrict access of those users to different controller methods.

The problem is that we are not controlling the event where a user enters a URL like "/documents/edit/1", where "1" is the ID of a document that shouldn't be managed by the current user because it does not belong to any of his groups. Also, for specific scenarios, we still need to be able to generate links for users to access to detail pages of entities that normally they wouldn't be able to.

We would like to find a way to achieve this without modifying the edit/details/delete controller methods to check the database and determine if the user should be able to manage that entity. 
We have been investigating different methods to achieve this restriction, but would like to know which would be the best practice for this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you already have claims based authentication, but you dont want to check in your storage of users that the current user has access to an ID. Then where do you want to check?

Comment: I'd like to find a more straightforward way to restrict access to those elements. One that doesn't involve a database lookup of the groups the user has access to, and the items that belong to that group to check for the entered ID.

Comment: You can create a cookie with information that contains list of groups where access from current user is allowed. You can also create custom filter that  checks if this cookie has the group, that user try to access, and deny access if cookie or group information in it is not found. May be it's wrong but still if you don't want to check something in database - add this to httprequest instead.

Comment: What are the methods you're considering?